# TextView overlaps ImageView inside a CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-cardview

I'm trying to do a ListView of CardViews.
The CardView contains an ImageView at the top and several TextViews at the bottom.
I manage to do everything right, although for some reason the image don't fit the CardView (so it gets cropped at the top of it) and the TextViews overlaps the rest of the image.
I tried a lot of different solutions, although nothing worked for me and i cam't figure out why.

The main layout:

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The CardView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/item_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/item_image_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/item_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the getView() methid:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View cardView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) this.getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card_list, parent, false);
        }
        else {
            cardView = convertView;
        }

        ImageView itemImage = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        TextView itemTitle = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        TextView imgDesc = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.item_image_desc);
        TextView itemDesc = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.item_desc);

        Item currItem = this.getItem(position);

        itemImage.setImageDrawable(currItem.mImageDrawable);
        itemTitle.setText(currItem.mTitle);
        imgDesc.setText(currItem.mDescription.imageDesc);
        itemDesc.setText(currItem.mDescription.descText);

        itemImage.setScaleX((float)1000 / currItem.mImageDrawable.getMinimumWidth());
        itemImage.setScaleY((float)1000 / currItem.mImageDrawable.getMinimumWidth());

        return (cardView);
    }
```

It seems like the CardViews have a max height or something..can't tell :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was all wrong. I realized that the setScale() methods I used only scaled the bitmap, and not the ImageView itself. Although when I tried to resize the ImageView before it was even layed down on the canvas, I got no luck either. So I did this:

Instead of trying to resizing the ImageView after I assigned it with a small bitmap, I resized the bitmap itself before setting it to the ImageView. Fixed everything :)